# Why does React component library like ant design bundle and transpile at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Recently, I tried to analyze famous react component library such as ant design. And I found something that I don't understand

[image: pic1]

This is a structure of directory of `antd`(ant design) inside `node_modules`

[image: pic2]

We can see bundled files.

[image: pic3]

And we can see transpiled files.

When I import some component from `antd` like this

```
import {Button} from "antd"
```

[image: pic4]

component come from transpiled files.

So my question here is that What `dist` folder (all of bundled files) do? when component just come from transpiled files?

Comment: They're the transpiled and type files. I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking what the type files are for?

Comment: No, I'm just curious that what dist folder do when using ant design library. Files in dist folder are bundled files.

Comment: `dist` is for your browser. Everything else is for you and your IDE

Comment: `d.ts` files are typescript type definitions so if you use typescript, it will get types for each component. That's the data types used in a component.

Comment: I understand that dist folder is for browser. Actually, I have a plan to deploy custom react component library. So when the library is only used for another react project, bundling process is not needed right?

Comment: Transpiling is only needed if you are using syntax/format that is not understood by the environment where your package will be used or when you are using a different language other than js. For example, your package may not be useable in all environments if it is written using es6 and is not transpiled down to es5. Browser support for es6 imports is only in very recent versions of some of the popular browsers....you may also need to transpile if your package is written in typescript or coffescript, or scalajs. None of those languages are understood natively by browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for distributing their library via the content delivery network [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/). See their [package.json](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/package.json#L46) which defines the `dist` dir as the entry point when `antd` is loaded via https://unpkg.com. They are bundled and minified to optimize their delivery when requested by a browser over HTTP. Basically for all the same reasons you probably bundle and minify your application code with a tool like webpack or rollup.

Comment: No problem. The other fields [`module`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) and [`main`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#main) in their `package.json` indicate entry points for other contexts as well.